# Find limit with factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to calculate the limit of 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}$$ 
and I am stuck. I tried n division but that didn't work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Note $(2n+1)!=(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)!$ so there will be a lot of cancellation.

Comment: as you can see pushing a little more the division will work

Answer (score 3):

We have:

$$
\begin{split} \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)*(2n)*(2n-1)!}&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n)} \\ &=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{4n^2+2n} \\ &=0\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice, expand the factorial as follows $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}$$ $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)\cdot (2n)\cdot (2n-1)!}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)\cdot (2n)}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}\cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2n}$$
$$=(0)(0)=\color{red}{0}$$