# Simplify and find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}$

Tags: limits, factorial

So I was calculating 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}$$
and couldn't solve it, so I saw the answer sheet and it said that the limit was $0$, I checked the process and they simplified the expression to 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n + 1)(2n)(2n − 1)!}$$
                      and then 
$$\frac{1}{(2n + 1)(2n)}$$
and said it was $0$

How did they achieved this?

Comment: They simplified the fraction.

Comment: $\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!} = \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n-1)!(2n)(2n+1)}$

Comment: The ratio simplifies to $\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n)}$. As $n\to\infty$, $\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n)}\to 0$. For imagine $n$ very large. Then $\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n)}$ is close to $0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas how do they get from (2n+1)! to (2n−1)!(2n)(2n+1)?

Comment: @ravelinx That's the definition of $n!$. $n! = (n)(n-1)\cdots(2)(1) = n(n-1)!$. So $(2n+1)! = (2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)\cdots(2)(1) = (2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)!$

Comment: Think concretely say $n=5$. The $2n+1=11$ and $2n-1=9$. We want $\frac{(9)(8)\cdots(1)}{(11)(10)(9)(8)\cdots(1)}$. Almost all the terms on top and bottom cancel, leaving $\frac{1}{(11)(10)}$.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1510409/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/)*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a smaller example. Consider 
$$5! = 5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1.$$
Notice that this can be expressed as
$$5! = 5\cdot(4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot) = 5\cdot4!.$$
Similarly
$$5! = 5\cdot4\cdot(3\cdot2\cdot1) = 5\cdot4\cdot3!$$
We can generalize to $k!$, 
$$k! = k(k-1)(k-2)\dotsm 2\cdot1$$
and in particular
$$k! = k(k-1)(k-2)!\tag a$$

Now,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!} &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)!}\tag b\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n)}\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
where in (b), I could use (a) as an aid by letting $k = 2n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: note that if the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty}\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}$$ converges $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}=0$$ you can use the ratio test to show that the series converges.