# find limit (lim n->infinity an) sequence an = (5n-1)!/(5n+1)!

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Determine whether the sequence converges or diverges. If it converges, find the limit. If it diverges write NONE.

$a_n = \frac {(5n-1)!}{(5n+1)!}$

$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=?$

---

the answer is $0$, but I have no idea how to get the value.

Comment: What do you get when you expand the factorials and simplify?

Comment: Hint: $(5n+1)! = (5n+1) \cdot 5n \cdot (5n-1)!$.

Comment: Oh I see. I was stupid. I thought  (5n+1)! = (5n+1)⋅(5n-4)⋅(5n-9).....

Comment: @DiWang you were thinking of double factorials it seems, which are a related concept.

Comment: Related: [$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1510409/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/)*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$a_n=\frac{(5n-1)!}{(5n+1)!}$$

$$a_n=\frac{1.2.3...(5n-1)}{1.2.3...(5n-1)5n(5n+1)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{5n(5n+1)}$$

So,

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=0.$$